# How to do 301 redirect to Sub page using htaccess file?

Tags: redirect, htaccess

I have 2 URLs. Basically page and sub page as below.

- `http://example.com/services`
- `http://example.com/services/service-1`

I want to add a 301 redirect rule in `.htaccess` file so that when someone opens the page:

```
http://example.com/services
```

it should redirect to its sub page:

```
http://example.com/services/service-1
```

I tried creating a rule in `.htaccess` file but it is going into redirection loop as its sub page. Below is my code for `.htaccess` file:

```
Redirect 301 /services /services/service-1
```

Update: Below is entire htaccess file code

```
RewriteRule ^for-patients$ /for-patients/children [R=302,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> Redirect 301 /services /services/service-1
> ```

This results in a redirect loop because the mod_alias `Redirect` directive is *prefix matching*. So, the source path `/services` matches the redirected path `/services/services-1`, etc. etc.

However, since you are already using mod_rewrite (as part of WordPress), you should also perform this redirect using mod_rewrite (as opposed to mod_alias). Different modules execute at different times during the request (mod_rewrite before mod_alias), despite the apparent order in `.htaccess`, so this can lead to some unexpected conflicts.

So, instead, try the following *before* your existing WordPress front-controller (ie. before the `# BEGIN WordPress` comment):

```
RewriteRule ^services$ /services/service-1 [R=302,L]
```

This matches the URL `/services` only. Note there is no slash prefix on the `RewriteRule` *pattern* when used in `.htaccess`.

This is a temporary (302) redirect. Change this to a 301 if this is intended to be permanent, but only after you have confirmed it is working OK. (301s are cached hard by the browser by default, so can make testing problematic.)

**UPDATE:** To make the above work with (or without) a trailing slash on the end of the requested URL then change the above to:

```
RewriteRule ^services/?$ /services/service-1 [R=302,L]
```

And if your target URL should have a trailing slash as well, then append this on the *substitution*. ie. `/services/service-1`, otherwise WordPress will either issue another redirect or you potentially create a duplicate content issue.

Comment: Its not redirecting. Below are the actual URLs. I used different one in the example.

RewriteRule ^for-patients$ /for-patients/children [R=302,L]

Comment: You will need to make sure your browser cache is cleared and that you have placed this directive at the top of your `.htaccess` file - the order is important. Please include your entire `.htaccess` in your question, so we can check this.

Comment: OK I have added entire htaccess file and I am testing it in incognito window in chrome every time I make changes in htaccess file. So if I change one line, I close the existing incognito window and open new one and check again.

Comment: Your `.htaccess` looks OK. Can you just confirm the URL is `example.com/for-patients` (no trailing slash)? And literally nothing happens, `example.com/for-patients` remains in the browsers address bar?

Comment: OK here is a thing I noticed
if I use it without trailing slash in the end, it is redirecting but as we know wordpress adds trailing slashes in all links so the links with trailing slashes are not redirecting.

Comment: Fixed it, changed it to ^for-patients\/$

Comment: Well, you did state the URL without a trailing slash in your question and WordPress can be configured to work both with and without a trailing slash (incidentally, these are two different URLs). I've updated my answer to work with an optional trailing slash, so it works for both `/services` and `/services/`. Incidentally, there is no need to backslash escape the slash in the `RewriteRule` _pattern_, so `^for-patients\/$` is the same as `^for-patients/$` to make the trailing slash mandatory.